# Sealing two stainless steel cylinders

Tags: oil, parts

I have 2 stainless steel cylinders (very thin) that I want to fit together. One has a diameter of 10cm and the other a bit more (around 11cm). I was thinking of sealing them together with an O-ring, but I don't know if they are available in that size. Also it has to be able to withstand up to 300 degrees Celsius. Anyone know what I could use for such a task?

Wielding them together is not possible because the material is too thin and I don't want to drill holes in them to avoid making them less waterproof (it will contain oil)

Thanks,

Comment: Do you expect to oil to be under pressure?

Comment: Only the pressure created by the oil being heated from room temperature to 300 degrees

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an o-ring, what you are looking for is an [O-ring splicing kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007EWZXVS). The kit allows you to form whatever size "O" you need. This kit from Permatex has different sizes (same as most of the kits out there) of cord so you can fill the gap as needed. You'd just need to provide a way to keep the o-ring in place. I would suggest running some kind of scoring around the outside of the inside cylinder (if that makes sense). If it were smaller, like tubing, I'd suggest using a tube cutter to do it, but because the size is much larger, you may be hard pressed to find something that large (10cm ~= 3.9" and 11cm ~= 4.3"). I think they make larger pipe cutters in that size ... it wouldn't take too much to make the score you need (thinking of more of a dent, really). If you don't put something for the o-ring to ride on, it will just push right out from between, if you can get it to stay put when you are fitting the two pieces together, especially if you are trying to contain oil. This is doubly true if there is any pressure involved as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find an adapter at a hardware store. If you want to make an o-ring, you may want to use silicone, or more precisely: silicone tubing. If you cut a piece off the tubing and roll it up like a condom, you will end up with a nice DIY o-ring. You may also be able to apply silicone to to smaller pipe, pull the larger one over it and allow it to set properly, although I wouldn't trust it if the contents are going to be under pressure.